# MYSQL Group By column

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL output

```
Type        | Unit | Model       |Ownership         
-----------------------------------------
Drill       | BM70 | DD110       | owned
Drill       | BM81 | DD110       | owned
Light Plant | X652 | 20 KW Tower | owned
Light Plant | LT12 | 20 KW Tower | rental
Light Plant | LT13 | 20 KW Tower | rental
Light Plant | G242 | 20 KW Tower | rental
```

What I am trying to display is the type, model and ownerhship which works fine except when I get to ownership. I need to breakup ownership between owned and rented so the output displayed after my query should look like

```
   Type        | Model        |Ownership         
    ------------------------------------
    Drill       | DD110       | owned
    Light Plant | 20 KW Tower | owned
    Light Plant | 20 KW Tower | rental
```

In the SQL statement I am using GROUP BY ownership gives me the 1st and 3rd line, but not the second. Here is my exact query, any help would be appreciated:

```
               $order = 'equipment_model_name';

               $get_equipment = "SELECT * FROM
                    rbs_equipment_type t
                        INNER JOIN
                    rbs_equipment_model m
                        ON t.id = m.model_type_id
                        INNER JOIN
                    rbs_equipment_unit u
                        ON m.model_id = u.equipment_unit_model_id
                    GROUP BY u.ownership
                    ORDER BY $order";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the type in the group by clause.  Since you didn't provide the columns name I'll guess something like :

```
GROUP BY t.type, u.ownership
```